# cmd - know if have multiple console processes with same name and taskkill them

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am using in cmd: tasklist /FI "session name eq console" to get list of console process es running. 
I need to know if there is more than one process with same name and taskkill them
Thanks for helping

Comment: `taskkill /FI "SESSION Eq Console"` Type `taskkill /?`.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look into this

[Kill all processes with the same name](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-kill-all-processes-with-the-same-name-in-Windows)

Answer (score 0):

You need to count every image name occurrence from [`tasklist` command](http://ss64.com/nt/tasklist.html) output, see next batch script *commented* code snippet:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions
    rem remove all variables with ? prefix (question mark)
for /F "tokens=1 delims==" %%G in ('2^>NUL set ?') do SET "%%~G="
    rem count
for /F "skip=1 tokens=1 delims=," %%G in ('
       tasklist /FI "SESSIONNAME eq Console" /FO csv
                                          ') do set /A "?%%~G+=1"
    rem use counters
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=?=" %%G in ('2^>NUL set ?') do (
    if %%H GTR 1 (
            rem next echo for debugging purposes
        echo              %%G process counter = %%H
        if /I NOT "%%G"=="cmd.exe" (
                rem taskkill command is merely displayed for debugging purposes
            ECHO taskkill /IM %%G
        ) else (
                rem needs more elaborated code to avoid killing the script itself
            echo       retain %%G
        )
    )
)
```

Output:

```
==> D:\bat\SO\37639505.bat
             chrome.exe process counter = 4
taskkill /IM chrome.exe
             cmd.exe process counter = 2
      retain cmd.exe
             iexplore.exe process counter = 3
taskkill /IM iexplore.exe
             powershell_ise.exe process counter = 2
taskkill /IM powershell_ise.exe

==>
```